# Nested Git Ignore ,Git Kraken Lists Ignored files as unstaged files

Tags: git, gitkraken

I want to keep my folder structure under version control.
the way I want to do this is by adding nested .gitignore files like below:
(note that I added some junk *.txt files to check gitignore works properly)

```
└── storage
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── public
    │   ├── .gitignore
    │   ├── logo
    │   │   ├── .gitignore
    │   │   └── logo.txt
    │   └── public.txt
    └── storage.txt
```

storage/.gitignore is :

```
*
!/public/
!.gitignore
```

storage/public/.gitignore is :

```
*
!/logo/
!.gitignore
```

storage/public/logo/.gitignore is :

```
*
!.gitignore
```

everything seems working fine my *.txt files are ignored and untracked which is the intended purpose.
The Problem is with Git Kraken GUI that shows `logo.txt` and `public.txt` as Unstaged Files like any other unignored files BUT the `storage.txt` is not there!

```
git status
```

> nothing to commit, working tree clean

```
git status --ignored
```

> storage/public/logo/logo.txt
>
> storage/public/public.txt
>
> storage/storage.txt
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

I tested with another git GUI (ungit) and the results are same as git cmd.

so what's the problem is? is it some kind of git Kraken bug? or I'm missing something about gitignore rules?
(note: this dummy project is fresh, and tested on two different computers)

Comment: maybe this is something to bring up with gitkraken's team?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  first i want to be sure its not my fault about git ignore

Comment: I doubt it. The cli output does not show those files.

Comment: According to the git documentation: "[*The underlying Git plumbing tools, such as git ls-files and git read-tree, read gitignore patterns specified by command-line options, or from files specified by command-line options.*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)" I would guess that gitkraken is using low-level plumbing commands and is incorrectly ignoring your `.gitignore` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GitKraken docs](https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-commits/staging/) say

> Note: GitKraken will only look at the .gitignore located at the root
>   of your repo directory. Nested .gitignore files are not parsed.

So it is a "feature" of GitKraken.